# Which OpenGL library should i use?

Tags: java, opengl, version

I have noticed that there are multiple GL libraries labeled GL11, GL12,GL13,GL14 and so on, i know the number is associated with the version number. I tried looking up the differences between the version numbers on google with no luck.

Would anybody mind explaining the differences, advantages, dis-advantages, and their recommendation?

Comment: Hi. You should mention that you use LWJGL as there are at least 3 Java bindings for the OpenGL API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not different OpenGL libraries, but basically LWJGL classes that contain OpenGL methods depending on which version of OpenGL that method was introduced in. So basically you could be using OpenGL 4.2 (GL42) but still need methods introduced in OpenGL 1.1 (GL11). Its just a way of organisation that will tell you when that method was added to OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you :) 
I will google the different methods in those classes